# How do I export from Blender to .obj file without there being hundreds of files?

Tags: export, obj

I am trying to export my Blender project to a .obj file, but everytime I do, there are a million little files created:

[image]

From a simple cube it created literally 500 files. I followed a tutorial on Youtube and in there they had only 1 file output.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to accomplish and what tutorial? Because you are exporting animation, each one of these files is 1 frame of your blender file in your timeline

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea how this file type works. Here's the tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNYg_kCdITY
I need a .obj file but I want only 1, like in the end of the video, not one from every single frame of my timeline.

Comment: Can you show me how your OBJ export window at 3:16 looks like? Are you sure you didn't check the last option Animation?

Comment: Well I did but I need the animation baked, that's why I tried with this format, on a forum I read that's how it is done, but I guess not. So I was unclear but I have an animation in Blender that uses a modifier in the animation, and in Unity it is not shown. So I am trying all the different file formats to be able to see my lattice modifier in Unity, without success so far :(

Comment: I think that file format is not issue, you can export animation easily into fbx file for example without any problems, you can try it yourself, just rotate cube and you will see that it is exported with animation as default... problem is that Lattice is not supported and as I found out it is not possible to use lattice as animation for export nor using it in unity... I think you need to do it differently, what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to achieve this:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244004/how-can-i-do-a-cartoon-like-cannon-firing-animation-thats-compatible-with-unity

Comment: The solution in your link works fine if you export your model to fbx, after it.