# How to export blender animation with displaced texture (displace modifier) and materials to GLB or USD

Tags: modifiers, export

I want to export animations with a displace modifier and materials to another format like .GLB or .USD for use in AR apps.

How can I do that? I read something about baking the animation. But I had basically the same sphere I started with.

I am using Blender 3.2

[image: animation]

[image: modifier]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do a cartoon-like cannon firing animation that's compatible with Unity (without lattice modifier)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244004/how-can-i-do-a-cartoon-like-cannon-firing-animation-thats-compatible-with-unity)

Comment: Hey Emir, thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately, it didn't work. The results I got were really different, really spiky and jagged compared to the original blob.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures