Need help exporting Blender animation using Displace modifier to Unity
I've created a 3d fire animation using a Displacement modifier on a base flame shape, driven by a noise texture, which is constantly translated in the direction the flame is pointing by an empty with a “#frame” driver (essentially I followed this YouTube tutorial). I can't seem to export the animation to Unity, which said no animation detected.
How can I export the animation to Unity ?


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30310/how-to-apply-the-ocean-modifier-to-get-an-animated-object

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Your second link only leads to a question with no answer... while you link to another question in the comments there. Why not directly use that link here as well instead of making people follow breadcrumbs?

@GordonBrinkmann My mistake, I was following the breadcrumbs myself. Meant to post the second link, fixed now, thanks

Can you give more details on how the fire animation works, please?

@TheLabCat I'm using displace modifier to the fire mesh and set the object to an empty plain axes, and setting the Z axis location using #frame. Basically I followed this youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzdlrgXssck

Try this >>> https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244004/how-can-i-do-a-cartoon-like-cannon-firing-animation-thats-compatible-with-unity/244018#244018

How the simulation was done is an essential detail. I’ve added it to the question. Meanwhile, what format were you trying to use for this? It’s worth asking but I think regardless this was bound to fail: Modifiers cannot be exported. They are unique to Blender. You’ll have to find some other way to store the displacement animation, possibly some cycling shape keys. I’d try to flesh this out and post it as an answer, but the question is still under review at the moment.

Use formats that can export mesh caches at each frame, like Alembic. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/322450/53447

That being said, there are probably better and more efficient ways to do that kind of visual effects in a game engine, like using shaders.
